# JavaScript Higher Order Function loop/recursion/confusion

Tags: javascript, for-loop, functional-programming

> Implement a function that takes a function as its first argument, a number num as its second argument, then executes the passed in function num times.

```
function repeat(operation, num) {
  var num_array = new Array(num);
  for(var i = 0; i < num_array.length; i++){
    return operation(num);
  }
}
// 
// The next lines are from a CLI, I did not make it.
// 
// Do not remove the line below
module.exports = repeat
```

**RESULTS**:

```
ACTUAL                             EXPECTED
------                             --------
"Called function 1 times."         "Called function 1 times."     
""                              != "Called function 2 times."     
null                            != ""                             
# FAIL
```

Why doesn't this work?

I am assuming that I am starting a function called repeat. Repeat has two parameters and takes two arguments.

For the loop I create an array which has a length which is equal to the num passed in.

I then start a for loop, setting a counter variable i to 0. Then I set a conditional which states that i should always be less than the length of the num_array which was created earlier. Then the counter i is incremented up by one using the ++.

For every time that the conditional is true, we should return the value of calling running the function operation and passing the num as an argument.

The last two lines allow for easy running of the program through command line with pre programmed arguments being used.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You do not need your array.  How did you test your function?

Comment: It's automatically tested by a CLI I am using. 

`ACTUAL                             EXPECTED
------                             --------
"Called function 1 times."         "Called function 1 times."     
""                              != "Called function 2 times."     
null                            != ""                             
# FAIL`

Comment: Add actual and expected results to your post (use `edit`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `return` statement is breaking out of the function on the first iteration of the loop. You need to remove the `return`, and just call the function like this:

```
function repeat(operation, num) {
  for(var i = 0; i < num; i++){
    operation(num);
  }
}
```

Note that I have removed the creation and iteration of the array, you do not need it for what you are doing here.

Also your initial question does not specify that you need to pass `num` to the function (but you do list it in your steps below), so you may be able to just do `operation()` instead of `operation(num)`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like the below, rather than `return`ing the result of the function `operation(num)` you want to store the value in teh array. `return` in a loop breaks out of the loop, so it would always only run once..

```
function repeat(operation, num) {
  var num_array = new Array(num);
  for(var i = 0; i < num_array.length; i++){
    num_array[i] = operation(num);
  }
}
// 
// The next lines are from a CLI, I did not make it.
// 
// Do not remove the line below
module.exports = repeat
```

Comment: That did it, thanks! That's a clever way to solve the problem. It's almost like the .map function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking why the loop is not running, it's because you have to run the function after defining it (I'm assuming you are not already calling the function somewhere else).

Once calling the function `repeat` you will see that it is exiting after one iteration. This is because you are returning the operation - returning causes the function to end. To stay in the loop you just need to call `operation()`, without the `return`.

Also you don't need to create an array, you can just use the counter you are defining in the for loop.

So the code would look something like this:

```
var op = function(arg) {console.log(arg);},
    n = 5;

function repeat(operation, num) {
  for(var i = 0; i < num; i++){
    operation(i);
  }
}

repeat(op ,n);

// The next lines are from a CLI, I did not make it.
// 
// Do not remove the line below
module.exports = repeat
```

Comment: The OP specifically states that the arguments are passed to the function from outside of his code.